# Is there a way to simplify $ \sum_{i=0}^k \cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{b^i}\right\rfloor \frac{2 \pi}{b}\right) $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, sums-of-squares

Sorry for my poor English language, but I really need help.
I would like to simplify the sum down in terms of: $n$, $k$, and $b$.
$$
\sum_{i=0}^k \cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\left\lfloor\frac{n}{b^i}\right\rfloor \frac{2 \pi}{b}\right)
$$
Another way to write the same sum is, if $n$ in radix $ b$  is:
$$
n=\sum_{j=0}^k a_i\cdot b^i
$$

So I can write same cosines sum as:

$$
\sum_{i=0}^k \cos^2{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+a_i \frac{2 \pi}{b}\right)}
$$

The way I would like to write the first summation is as a function of a constant times a cosine of some angle.

Comment: What is being squared?  The cosine or the argument?  That is, do you mean $\cos^2\left(\frac\pi2+a_i\frac{2\pi}b\right)$ or do you mean $\cos\left(\left(\frac\pi2+a_i\frac{2\pi}b\right)^2\right)$?

Comment: first one, cosine are in square, not angle

Comment: I think it would be as well to edit the question that way, to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: fixed @saulspatz

Comment: Some simplification comes from $\cos^2 x = \frac12(1+\cos 2x)$ and so $\cos^2(\frac\pi2+y)=\frac12(1+\cos(\pi+2y))=\frac12(1-\cos(2y))$. Beyond that, each summand could be arbitrary so I don't see what more can be done.

Comment: @GregMartin  thank you very much i will try to work better on it. And believe me, this is only half the problem